# How can I turn off iOS alerts for a given account, without turning them off app by app

Tags: newrelic

How can I turn off iOS notifications for my New Relic account, without either:

- Going app-by-app and turning them off there; or
- Turning off push notifications for the New Relic iOS apps in the iOS preferences.

I run multiple New Relic accounts, I want to be able to keep push alerts for some accounts but disable them completely for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to globally disable only the iOS notifications on all applications in an account.

You could disable ALL notifications in a New Relic account via the API by building a script to run though each of your applications and set the value of alerts-enabled to false.

https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic_api#update-an-applications-settings

Feature requests can be submitted via support.newrelic.com

Comment: Using XmlStarlet the following worked for me: for i in $(curl --header "x-api-key: api key" https://api.newrelic.com/api/v1/accounts/:account/applications.xml | xml sel -t -v "//id"); do curl --header "x-api-key: api key" -X PUT -d "alerts_enabled=false" https://api.newrelic.com/api/v1/accounts/:account/application_settings/$i.xml; done;

Answer (score 0):

You should submit a feature request at https://support.newrelic.com for this.